# What is the best way to consume hyperlinked APIs on Android?

Tags: java, android, json, rest, retrofit2

If I had a JSON response like below (e.g. adapted from `swapi.co/api/people/1`):

```
{
    "name": "Luke Skywalker",
    "height": "172",
    "mass": "77",
    "films": [
        "https://swapi.co/api/films/2/",
        "https://swapi.co/api/films/6/",
        "https://swapi.co/api/films/3/",
        "https://swapi.co/api/films/1/",
        "https://swapi.co/api/films/7/"
    ]
}
```

We can see that `films` is represented as an array of links to its detail pages. If I would like to show all of this information on a single screen in an Android app, what is the best way to do so? Currently I am thinking of using Retrofit and creating a class like such:

```
public class Person {
    public String name;
    public String height;
    public String mass;
    public String[] filmUrls; // or should this be public Film films;
}
```

But I am rather confused on what is the best way to parse the URLs to show all related information.

Comment: So you want to display the details of all the films on the same page with `name`,`height`, etc?

Comment: Yes, that would be it.

Comment: You will have to make a request for each URL in the `films` list to get the response. Pratik Butani answer is a good starting point. I recommend you look at some tutorials with Retrofit if you're not familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

So your Model Class is just like:

```
public class Example {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("height")
    @Expose
    private String height;
    @SerializedName("mass")
    @Expose
    private String mass;
    @SerializedName("films")
    @Expose
    private List<String> films = null;

    public String getName() {
    return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }

    public String getHeight() {
    return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(String height) {
    this.height = height;
    }

    public String getMass() {
    return mass;
    }

    public void setMass(String mass) {
    this.mass = mass;
    }

    public List<String> getFilms() {
    return films;
    }

    public void setFilms(List<String> films) {
    this.films = films;
    }

}
```

And yes, You can go with Retrofit. It will be easy and efficient.

Comment: (Using the Star Wars API example) Thank you for taking your time to answer. If i would like to the show information of Person and all information of its related Films together, what would make good design? Should I call a for loop for all of the film URLs, calling GET filmDetail per loop?